# Regex can't catch space before quote

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a regex for catch illegal char (for specific API), looks like :

```
const regexIllegalChar: RegExp = new RegExp(
  `[^(\\w)(\\s)(\\')(\\.)(\\-)(\\/)(\\+)(\\=)(\\@)(\\_)(\\:)(\\,)(É)(È)(Ê)(Ë)(À)(Â)(Ä)(Ô)(Ö)(Û)(Ü)(Î)(Ï)]*`,
  'gi'
);
```

But when I type `”` with IOS tablet (the one looks like `<<` ), a space is automatically added before or after (depend if opening or closing word), and this space is not catched.

Exemple :

```
foo bar => foobar : OK
foo"bar (manualy removed automatic space) => foo"bar : OK
foo "bar (manualy removed automatic space, and add a normal one) => foo"bar : OK
foo[automatic_space]"bar => foo[automatic_space]"bar : NOK
```

Comment: Your regex is written in a very confusing way, it  is the same as ```/[^-\w\s'.\/+=@:,ÉÈÊËÀÂÄÔÖÛÜÎÏ]*/gi```. Not sure what code you are using it in, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qSOkK/1)

Comment: Wictor, and including parentheses (once) :-)

Comment: Why don't you whitelist characters instead of blacklisting

Comment: @AvcS A use-case of using blacklisting characters is multi-lingual inputs ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can try whitelisting of legal characters instead of blacklisting illegal characters, this will catch the unknown character IOS is inserting in the text.

```
(str.match(/[a-z0-9_"]+/gi) || []).join('')
```